# Output graylog logs to another graylog

Tags: logging, graylog2, graylog, gelf

I'm trying to output all the logs from a Graylog server to another one.
I would like to make this from multiple servers to the same one (categorizing them to keep a track on which log come from which server)

Does somebody have an idea on how I could do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current stable release of Graylog I would use the GELF Output of Graylog that can send a stream from one Graylog to the GELF Input of another Graylog.

Another option might be to use one of the Plugins that allows you to use Kafka or AMQP outputs and read via the given inputs the data in the second Graylog, that would give you a queue to not run into issues when the network connection is flacky, your receiver Graylog has issues or is overwhelmed by messages.

In upcoming versions - at least for the Enterprise Features - their is a dedicated output/input for this specific features that includes journaling and makes that more reliable.